# Is there a better way to rotate through 3 different states (A, B, A+B)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I would like to be able to rotate through 3 states (A, B, A+B) with one momentary push button (M) as follows:

- starting state: A is high, B is high
- after having pressed on M a 1st time : A is high, B is low
- after having pressed on M a 2nd time : A is low, B is high
- after having pressed on M : back to starting state

I designed a [circuit achieving this behavior](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2aAWB8CcBmSy0AOBBAdkJAWUssgCgwSQBaMU6sMAJhbDTXDcoUBkzDUs1AiEnCEdAO7DuFSCC5cB9Ja3bh%20vPRq2LD1Y8Ivazgnruo4e1zj0e2Z1a-ZBvmhNW5e-j52wcFBATwuISIAsj7IFNFocO5qYKI4LMGy4h6WcnQAziya6QbefFrgIAAuAE4ArgCmdABKpSn6Asxl%20WpqXUgDUNDyjOUCbOaQSXpqTpSm0eKT4MgDywZgWKHpuyI6wTt74PPLQlyESQZXqqJTt6Q8FlzPBWrySnkqyleH6io%20WisnojFcXH2rkS4AOC0K8RwMJOIBSUOUogh6SESKSQnhSC%207ju7lWAKqgI4-y4QOc1KBvysy2pmnUrKZSle7NZ0wBFl5kLmnlM-KMDPOnPZ7xp5ne1hl%20UcalBIp5Rh5-3lGooSvAmtMuoF4uFnKBbxeZtmfMtOsh6it9CAA) as a falstad simulation.
It seems to work fine, however it requires 2 flipflops, 2 OR gates, 1 NOR, 1 XOR and 1 AND gate.

Is there any way to simplify it ? Or are you aware of an IC able to achieve this kind of behavior with less parts involved ?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Note: The logic is meant to energize 2 different relays. The starting state can be different as the one above (but at least A or B must be high).

Comment: it's a 2 bit binary counter ... counts 0 to 2 ... outputs are taken from Q'

Comment: Should be able to do it with 2 FFs and one gate to eliminate the 4th state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I just deleted all the output gates.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2aAWB8CcBmSy0AOBBAdkJAWUssgCgwSQBaMU6sMAJhbDTXDcoUBkzDUs1AiEnD6Ad2HcKkEFy4CFvduH7bq6zXUWsdh4ea2mOQ6yBw8tnHg8E9ZVttVfNCq11Z+9jy+qkGB-jzOwSIAsvaQAtFocG5KojgsQbLiMtSqPEgIdADOLBqqfAJ2VUogAC4ATgCuAKZ0AErlKbrVFXlyID1IqqPQxYo4yBRgWCFBs47GWZVzK+A6ThxcKuA7cfbT4Gtorovpk4ngyJVC4qPLeEk3CUlC9FyQpIczQlMz+wEACE6J9vv9ji4jp8KAIAIJ0IA) and picked the flip-flop terminals that followd your rules.

Comment: Thank you, I was just overcomplicating things :-)